# Pyspark: Extracting rows of a dataframe where value contains a string of characters

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using pyspark and I have a large dataframe with only a single column of values, of which each row is a long string of characters:

```
col1
-------
'2020-11-20;id09;150.09,-20.02'
'2020-11-20;id44;151.78,-25.14'
'2020-11-20;id78;148.24,-22.67'
'2020-11-20;id55;149.77,-27.89'
...
...
...
```

I'm trying to extract rows of the dataframe where 'idxx' matches a list of strings such as ["id01", "id02", "id22", "id77", ...]. Currently, the way I extract rows from the dataframe is:

```
df.filter(df.col1.contains("id01") | df.col1.contains("id02") | df.col1.contains("id22") | ... )
```

Is there a way to make this more efficient instead of having to hard code every string item into the filter function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

str_list = ["id01", "id02", "id22", "id77"]
df.filter(reduce(or_, [df.col1.contains(s) for s in str_list]))
```

Answer (score 5):

Try with `.rlike` operator in pyspark.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show(10,False)
#+-----------------------------+
#|col1                         |
#+-----------------------------+
#|2020-11-20;id09;150.09,-20.02|
#|2020-11-20;id44;151.78,-25.14|
#|2020-11-20;id78;148.24,-22.67|
#+-----------------------------+

#(id09|id78) match either id09 or id78
#for your case use this df.filter(col("col1").rlike('(id01|id02|id22)')).show(10,False)

df.filter(col("col1").rlike('(id09|id78)')).show(10,False)
#+-----------------------------+
#|col1                         |
#+-----------------------------+
#|2020-11-20;id09;150.09,-20.02|
#|2020-11-20;id78;148.24,-22.67|
#+-----------------------------+
```